# label More Information - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tabs, luma-theme

how do I change the text on the More Info tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override **catalog_product_view.xml** under

```
app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

If you want to override via theme, you should place this file under

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout
```

If you want to place it into module instead, place it under

```
app/code/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/view/frontend/layout
```

`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="additional" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">your_name</argument>
            </arguments>
         </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the following template file and change the text

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

Comment: The change not work

Answer (score 0):

I changed "More Information" through the en_US.csv generated in my child theme.
Find the line below and modify the second "More Information."

"More Information","More Information",module,Magento_Catalog

If you need to generate your child en_US.csv I used a combination of these to guides to make mine (substituting French for US):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict

https://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-translation/

Hope that helps.

Comment: If there are more than 1 occurrences on the string, your method doesn't work.